# REGEXP not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to find record with names which have non-alpha numeric characters.

I thought that I could do it with REGEXP

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Then I referred another SO question

[How can I find non-ASCII characters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql)

I found I could use this query :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE NOT columnToCheck REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

But it returns me zero rows . If I replaced the command to :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnToCheck REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

It returns me all the rows!!.

I tried some basic commands  :

```
SELECT 'justffalnums' REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]'; returns 1
```

which is correct but

```
SELECT 'justff?alnums ' REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]'; also returns 1
```

I don't understand why it returs one. It should return 0 as it has space and also a '?' .

Is there anything to be enable in mysql for the regexp to work ?

I am using mysql 5.0 and tried with 5.1 too .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `^` (string begins) and `$` (string ends) as well as an operator saying a certain number of alphanum's to use. Below I used `+` which means one or more.

```
SELECT 'justff?alnums ' REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$';
-- only contains alphanumns => 0

SELECT 'justff?alnums ' REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+';
-- just begins with alphanum => 1

SELECT 'justff?alnums ' REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]+$';
-- just ends with alphanum => 0
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '^[[:alnum:]]+$'.

Answer (score 0):

The regex that you've given does not say that the entire field has to contain the characters in question.  You can use the negation character `^` at the beginning of a character set.

```
SELECT 'justff?alnums' REGEXP '[^A-Za-z0-9]'; returns 1
SELECT 'justffalnums' REGEXP '[^A-Za-z0-9]'; returns 0
```