# Finding strange characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

A year back, we migrated our data to MySQL. Due to encoding mismatch, a number of strange characters(Ã,ª, €, etc) got inserted into the records. We would like to track all such characters in the whole database.

I tried the following query.

```
 select * from <table_name> where <field_name> regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9&,$\'"() .-]'
```

It gives me all the entries which have any character(s) apart from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, &, comma, dollar, single-quotation, double-quotation, parenthesis, space, period, hyphen in the `<field_name>` of the particular table.

But it would take a lot of time to find all the strange characters as we have approximately 93 table with approximately 20 fields each.

Is there a better approach to resolve the issue?

Re-importing again with proper encoding setting is not an option because the data has changed a lot since then.

Comment: Have you identified and fixed the encoding mismatch? If so, it might be best to fix the errors one-by-one rather than trying to keep track.

Comment: We know what was the encoding mismatch. But its too late to correct it and re-migrate.
And finding out all the characters using a query like what I mentioned in the question would require a lot of time. Isn't there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters you mention look like utf-8 data rendered as if it were ASCII or Latin-1 eight bit characters.

Here's a post on how to find the problems. It works better than your approach and is super-disciplined about character set matching.

[How can I find non-ASCII characters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql/11741314#11741314)

Can you provide the table definition of one of the tables containing this junk? That way we can see the character set and collation settings of the table and columns.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Recipe` (
 `Recipe_Id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Language` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `Brand_Id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
 `Is_Deleted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
 `Brand_Reference_No` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `Display_Title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
... so on.

I saw your answer on the other link. Much better approach then mine.