# MYSQL latin1 and utf8 after mysqldump

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I did a backup like that :

Server A :
mysqldump --all-databases -u user -ppwd --default-character-set=latin1 > backup.sql

Server B :
mysql -u user -ppwd --default-character-set=latin1 < backup.sql

But now, when I show datas from MYSQL with PHP, I have something like that :
"GÃ©nÃ©ral".

My html page is in latin1. My database is in latin1.

If I put utf8_decode($mydata); I get the right result.
How can I configure MYSQL to have the database results in latin1 ?

From Server B :

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_name like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have problems with character sets on backups, you should try doing the backup and restore command in the good way, without using the `<` or `>` redirectors of the shell because that redirection can break the character set of the database text.

**Backup**

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt --all-databases -r backup.sql
```

**Restore**

```
mysql -uuser -p --default-character-set=utf8 database
mysql> SET names 'utf8';
mysql> SOURCE backup.sql;
```

Comment: it worked, but I also did a search replace in the backup.sql file for `s/latin1/utf8/`, I also added the two arguments on dump `mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 --set-charset`

Answer (score 0):

Your database contains some data that's encoded with utf-8, but you have stored it in table columns declared to be latin1.  Presumably you want GÃ©nÃ©ral to be displayed as Général.

You're going to have to repair your data to fix this.  To find the offending data, see this article.

[How can I find non-ASCII characters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql/11741314#11741314)

Comment: In fact, when i'm using PHPMyAdmin, I can see the right data in the table.

In the table it's "Général", but when I display the data with my PHP script I get "GÃ©nÃ©ral". If in the PHP script I put "utf8_decode()" the data shows as "Général".

So I don't think that my data has to be fixed.

Comment: I bet you can't search for "Général" and find that record. PhpMyAdmin uses a web browser to display your data. The browser translates your data from encoded latin1 (e.g.  GÃ©nÃ©ral) to utf-8, so it's going to display your misencoded data correctly.  The utf8_decode() call in php does the same thing. Try strlen().  I bet you find the length is 6, not 8.