# mySql - find non-Ascii character in html

Tags: mysql, regex, character-encoding

I'm trying to find all non-asci characters I have in my DB in a specific table and column. In that column are stored Html description, and in some of them I've exotic or non-existing characters (for example:  Hà¶ganà¤s ).

I'm triyng to match them with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM project_version WHERE description REGEXP '[^()\x00-\xFF\,\.-\<\>="\' /:;&=]'
```

But I think I'm missing something, cause it returns all of my records. Does anyone any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql) that has multiple answers; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11741314/2091410) may be the best - it was added much later so it doesn't have as many upvotes, but it looks solid.

Comment: ASCII is actually only 0x00-0x7F, so `[^\x00-\x7F]` or `[\x80-\xFF]` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving hyphen to start or end otherwise it needs to be escaped also `^` will be treated as literal `^` in character class:

```
SELECT * FROM project_version WHERE description REGEXP '[()\x00-\x7F,.<>="\' /:;&=-]'
```