# MySQL Regex for Non English Characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I've looked all over Stack-Overflow and Google for a simple REGEX for MySQL that satisfies the following requirements:

- Finds all rows with a Non English Characters (ö, etc)
- Match any part of the column not just the first or last
- Allowed characters are anything but foreign characters (acceptable: _, A-Z, 0-9, # , " ' ( ) - @)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would this help? [find columns with non-ASCII characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252544/3110638)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE NOT columnToCheck REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

Comment: `REGEXP` is not multibyte safe: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: This is a very useful answer