# SQLAlchemy match() using Natural Language instead of Boolean

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy has a `.match()` function that helps to search full-text. However, the default search is in `BOOLEAN MODE`. How can I change the `BOOLEAN MODE` to `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`?

Reason for doing this is because I need to search for hyphenated text and periods. I know there is this source: [MySQL Full Text Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696235/mysql-full-text-period)
However, I don't want to change any source file or configure my MySQL settings.

How to change `.match()` function to `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`?

Comment: Looks like you cannot: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py#L1281. You'll likely have better luck using the generic `op()` or `text()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä can I put the hyphenated words into a list/array and use .like() for each value in the array?