# how to search special characters in fulltext index mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have created a `fulltext index` in `mysql`.

I configured the index by song name, but the song title consisting only of special characters cannot be searched.

music[table] - title[column] is indexed, settings `innodb_ft_min_token_size` = 1, `stopword` is disabled.

If the song name is '$$$'.

```sql
select * from music where match(title) against('$$$' in boolean mode);
select * from music where match(title) against('"$$$"' in boolean mode);
select * from music where match(title) against('+$$$*' in boolean mode);
```

None of the above codes work, and even just one $ gives the same result. (numbers, English have been confirmed to operate normally.)

I have a question because I don't know which setting to change after this..!

Comment: What is your client's language?  (I am checking for whether `$` is being messed with it.)

Comment: @RickJames Most languages ​​are in English.
For $, it is to find 'dollar($$$)'.

Comment: I mean Java/PHP/VB/JS/...

Comment: @RickJames I'm sorry.... I use `nestjs` and `typeorm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `$` is not considered by MySQL a word character, it is not being added to the index and therefore cannot be used for fulltext search. In this case you do not have the option to search without symbols, which worked for my data. I can see these other possibilities:

- Revert to LIKE when searching entirely or mostly for symbols.

```
select * from music where title LIKE '%$$$%'
```

- Add `$` to word characters as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21696394/999198)

Comment: This is an impossible in mysql. Thanks for the reply.