# Update column where non-ascii characters are found

Tags: mysql

[Using this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql), I'm able to find non-ascii characters using this query below.  The only problem is that I still don't know what the value of the non-ascii character is in some of the records.  How do I simply take any non-ascii character found and update it with a simple space?

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM tableName 
 WHERE columnToCheck <> CONVERT(columnToCheck USING ASCII)
```

Comment: Unfortunately mysql doesn't support regex-based replace, which would be the simplest approach if available. I would use your favorite app language to read, use regex replace, then write back to the db

Comment: Not in MySQL directly usually. I'd do it in the application, [or you can install something like this](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg)