# Mysql Regex, Sort out corrupted Time Formats

Tags: mysql

I have a column called "Time" this column is currently set to Varchar since i have some corrupted Time in some updates.Some Time has non ASCII characters etc. So how can i sort out all these corrupted and non properly formated time fields and set to NULL ? So that i can safely convert the Time column back to DateTime. The normal time fields in the updates are usually  in the format of `2013-07-24 14:37:56`

I was thinking of sorting it out by doing something like :

```
SELECT * FROM updates WHERE TIME not LIKE '....-..-.. ..:..:..'
```

But i don't know if that is the right regex approach and most efficient.

[image]

Comment: If you just need to find those with non ASCII chars, [see this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql)

Comment: @MYSQLnoob: Corrupted means what? Can you show some sample records?

Comment: @NoobEditor because, it doesn't work ? No errors just not the expected results

Comment: @Alon_A i used that already. It's not enough for those which are corrupted and ASCII

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM updates WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`TIME`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') IS NULL
```

Function `DATE_FORMAT` will try to format `TIME` in 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format, if function is not able to format `TIME` it will return `NULL`, so that's how you'll know which one is not in appropriate format and then you can handle them manually or set them to null with `UPDATE` query

Comment: When posting answers, please add and explanation describing what you changed or added or how it works or something. Even though your answer may be the solution, it's likely that some people who read this don't understand what it means or how it works.

Comment: i totally agree with you, sorry for not explained answer. i updated my answer with an explanation, hope it is ok now

Answer (score 0):

You could try using MySQL [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) on your varchar column:

```
update updates set `time` = null 
where str_to_date(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

> *So how can i sort out all these corrupted and non properly formated time fields and set to NULL ?*

If `CAST` of such `TIME` column returns a `NULL`, then you can set it to `NULL` or a desired date time string value.

**Example with Select**:

```
mysql> select @ts:=cast( '2013-07╞ƒ~¥14:37:56' as datetime ) ts, @ts is null;
+------+-------------+
| ts   | @ts is null |
+------+-------------+
| NULL |           1 |
+------+-------------+
```

**Example for update**:

```
update table_name 
   set time_coumn = null -- or a valid date time string value
 where cast( time_column as datetime ) is null
```

Once you have set the column value to a `NULL`, you can then set valid `datetime` values for those records which have `NULL` values.