# How do I search for strings containing accented characters in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `x` with column `LegalName` since they are over 10K+, I want to write a query that returns me names that have accents. (á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ). Is there a better way other than actually searching for them using `where`? Example of my current SQL query : `Select * from x  WHERE LegalName LIKE '%é%'` and i have added a lot of 'or' statements. I am bound to miss out something. Any recommendations?

Comment: quick/dirty possibility: convert to a charset that doesn't support accents, so theoretically `á` would become a plain `a`, then you do a strict comparison of the deaccented string against the original. if they're different, then you've got accented chars.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql