# How can I fetch query with letter æ

Tags: mysql

it does not compute when I use the letter æ
I have tried with Collation latin1_Swedish_Ci and latin1_Danish_Ci which are the only two that I have found to work with æ ø å

```
$sql="SELECT MIN(PrisMel) FROM `toosttable` WHERE `Vare` = 'Lærer'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

The fetched value is a number.

Answer (score 0):

To get these characters printed you can maybe use `utf8_encode("YOUR SQL-QUERY STRING")` .

That should convert your string into an utf8-encoded one and give it to your `mysqli_query()` function.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it did not work :c thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to give the query like this.

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name like '%[^a-z, .-™]%';
```

Comment: Thanks for trying :) With your suggestion I get this error for all rows: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ... on line 201

Comment: try something like SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE NOT columnToCheck REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]'; to make sure ae is getting selected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql

Comment: any progress on that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Simply set the charset with this  `mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");` Here is the full code to be exact:

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','toostdatabase');
                                // Check connection
                                if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                                {
                                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                                }
                                mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

$sql = "SELECT MIN(PrisMel) FROM `toosttable` WHERE `Vare` = 'Lærer'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```