# MySQL Replace Part of String (Longtext)

Tags: mysql, replace, longtext

After a CONCAT from various other fields, I am trying to clean up the data - specifically removing multiple separators... but it affects 0 records (out of several thousand.)

```
UPDATE CONTACTS
SET NOTES = REPLACE(NOTES, "%- - - -%", "-")
WHERE NOTES = 53388 LIMIT 1
```

The 'where' is just for testing.

Example Before

```
ID | NOTES
1 | - - - - Hi there
2 | Sun is hot today - - - -
3 | Nice - - - - to be on stackoverflow
4 | This record is just - fine.
```

Required Result

```
ID | NOTES
1 |  Hi there
2 | Sun is hot today 
3 | Nice  to be on stackoverflow
4 | This record is just - fine.
```

I've checked and double checked the statement but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

It doesn't affect multiple rows or individual rows.

The field is longtext is that makes any difference?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE CONTACTS SET NOTES = REPLACE(TRIM(NOTES),'- - - -','');
```

**Result**:

Before:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACTS;
+------+-------------------------------------+
| ID   | NOTES                               |
+------+-------------------------------------+
|    1 | - - - - Hi there                    |
|    2 | Sun is hot today - - - -            |
|    3 | Nice - - - - to be on stackoverflow |
|    4 | This record is just - fine.         |
+------+-------------------------------------+
```

After:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACTS;
+------+------------------------------+
| ID   | NOTES                        |
+------+------------------------------+
|    1 |  Hi there                    |
|    2 | Sun is hot today             |
|    3 | Nice  to be on stackoverflow |
|    4 | This record is just - fine.  |
+------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: OK, there's some very odd behavior here.  This suggestion in itself doesn't work but does if I just look for a single '-', where it replaces all instances!!  I've gone over all the reconds and settled for a replacement of ' -' for '' which eliminates most of the duplicates.

Comment: You can try and run this query to see how many records are candidates for update. `SELECT * FROM CONTACTS WHERE TRIM(NOTES) LIKE '%- - - -%';` One possibility is that the space may actually be some non-printing character.

Comment: You can take a look at this thread, and try the queries and see if you can find something odd (like non-printing characters) in `NOTES` column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to replace this `%- - - -%` with `-`. In your sample data there are no `%` signs. You've probably mistaken it with `%` sign which matches any sequence of zero or more characters in `LIKE` expression.

Just use it without percent sign, and add additional spaces before/after if needed:

```
REPLACE(NOTES, "- - - -", "-")
```

If you need something more sophisticated logic and have MySQL version 8.0+ then you could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.

Comment: Thanks, but that was my first attempt and it doesn't work without wildcards either :/

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.0.27 - no abuse please!  This process is actually updating the DB and front UI before upgrading the whole LAMP

Comment: Either there's something I can't see in your data or I don't know what it is. Please create a sample on http://sqlfiddle.com with your version