# How to search values from database using ā, è

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I want search ā, è.. this special characters and show in page, but when i search the value its converting into different characters. am getting 'nor result found

my html:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

this is my php code

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test2");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect
   to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  $ksl = $_GET['name'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM app WHERE texts LIKE '%$ksl%' ";

  if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $row['texts'];
          }
      } else{
          echo "No records matching your query were found.";
      }
  } else{
      echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

  // Close connection
  mysqli_close($conn);

}


?>
```

my js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').keyup(function(){
      var gk = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {
          'submit': true,
          'name' : gk,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#testa').html(data);
        }
      });
    })
  });
</script>
```

how to use special characters in search?

Comment: Probably a Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find non-ASCII characters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't do this in mysql. Some workarounds of this use HEX values instead to search for these accents, a work around that I have used ages ago, which is not an ideal way  but it did work is to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `app` WHERE `text` REGEXP '(s|š|Š|[sšŠ])(i|í|Í|[iíÍ])(r|ŕ|Ŕ| 
.   ř|Ř|[rŕŔřŘ])(e|é|É|ě|Ě|[eéÉěĚ])(n|ň|Ň|[nňŇ])(A|a|á|Á|ä|Ä|0|[AaáÁäÄ0])'
```

Or from doing some more research I found a way to use something like this

```
SELECT whateverYouWant
FROM app 
WHERE text <> CONVERT(columnToCheck USING ASCII)
```

> The CONVERT(col USING charset) function will turns the unconvertable characters into replacement characters. Then, the converted and unconverted text will be unequal.

Take a look at this link to find more information about this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-repertoire.html

Comment: its working, but how to use " where text like '%$thepostvalue%" in this section "SELECT whateverYouWant
FROM app 
WHERE text <> CONVERT(columnToCheck USING ASCII)"

Comment: I haven't tried this personally but I imagine you'd be able to `bind_value() ` and then use that in the statement. Unsure about how well documented that is though

Comment: @maffidesigners was my answer helpful?

Comment: actually, it's working, but the problem with bind the value (''when I search particular charset value not working "). am trying with given reference. thank you

Comment: No problem, keep me posted and if it works accept the answer, if not don't so other people can give it a go!

Comment: What solution are you trying to implement? first example or the second one? @maffidesigners

Comment: Any joy @maffidesigners